# Touch the blue paper

Tags: idioms, expressions

I have recently heard that phrase (*touch the blue paper*) from a native English speaker¹. Is it an erroneous alteration of the expression *light the blue touchpaper* or is it a correct² phrase in its own right?

<sup>1. from the West Midlands, if that matters.
  2. by *correct*, I mean *in current idiomatic usage*</sup>

Comment: Just an interesting side-note. I remember looking up this phrase (*light the blue touch paper*) a while ago when it was used in the dialog of the classic *Doctor Who* television show to refer to the threat of a fringe group **initiating a global nuclear disaster**. The serial name was ["Robot"](http://www.drwhoguide.com/who_4a.htm) which aired in 1974-1975 (sorry, I don't remember the specific episode number within the 4-part serial).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds to me like he has misquoted 'Light the blue touch-paper', as you suspected. There is no such idiom as 'touch the blue paper'. Nobody's perfect!

Comment: I've never heard of either expression.  Where do they come from?

Comment: It means 'to set something off', especially an angry or excited reaction. It refers to the saltpetre-saturated paper used to ignite fireworks and other explosives. Only 'light the blue touch-paper' is actually an idiom, the other is a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It's an alteration of `light the blue touch paper`. Blue touch paper is a type of fuse used in explosives. The phrase `light the blue touch paper` thus gives the imagery of doing something which causes a figurative explosion of emotion.

`Blue paper` has no special significance, nor does touching blue paper. The closest you could get is touching a blueprint (a construction plan for a building), and there's no special significance to touching those as well.

Comment: My first thought was the blue/pink result you get from a litmus test, but I have no knowledge of that having any sort of idiomatic usage.